# How do I upload a picture on a server after capturing it?

Tags: android

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
    File extBaseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(extBaseDir.getAbsoluteFile() + "/Nrega/data");

    // String upLoadServerUri =
    // "http://117.239.190.115/MobilePHP/upload_media_test1.php";
    String upLoadServerUri = "Server path";

    final String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    String fileName1 = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(fileName1);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
        return 0;
    }
    try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP
                                                            // connection
                                                            // to
                                                            // the URL
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        // dos1 = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer
                                                        // of
                                                        // maximum size

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage
                + ": " + serverResponseCode);
        if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    fileName + "\nFile Upload to Server Complete.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            /*
             * runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
             * 
             * Toast.makeText(getActivity(), fileName +
             * "\nFile Upload to Server Complete.",
             * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } });
             */
        } else {
            /*
             * new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
             * runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
             * Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error in Sending File",
             * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             * 
             * } }); File extBaseDir = Environment
             * .getExternalStorageDirectory(); File file = new
             * File(extBaseDir.getAbsoluteFile() + "/GeoStamping/sys");
             * final String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" +
             * "unsent.dat"; File ff = new File(filePath); try { String[] d
             * = preread(); BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( new
             * FileWriter(filePath)); for (int j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
             * out.write(d[j].toString() + "\n"); } out.write(txtfilename2 +
             * ".txt\n"); out.write(txtfilename2 + ".jpg\n"); out.flush();
             * out.close(); } catch (Exception e) { // TODO Auto-generated
             * catch block e.printStackTrace(); } } }).start();
             */
        }

        // close the streams //
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
        showError("Error : MalformedURLException ");
        // showError("Error : MalformedURLException " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        showError("Error : IOException ");
        // showError("Error : IOException " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        // int er = e.printStackTrace();
        // showError(e.printStackTrace());

        showError(e.toString());
    }
    // dialog.dismiss();
    return serverResponseCode;
}
```

Its working for me for uploading any file but i am not getting path of the image  file to upload using this method please help i am very infant in android

Comment: your code is a little bit hard to read. Can you add a comment please to the part where you are saving the picture locally, before uploading it? I don't see it .

Comment: Are you sure your image is captured properly? AFAIR Android camera listener gives you a byte array, so you have to save it into a file yourself.

Comment: can u guide me how to get path of recently stored image